Where to find chess videos where an expert explains their moves real-time
I have very much benefitted from Simon Williams' "Longer Games" playlist, where he plays various opponents with 15 minutes per side, all the while sharing about what he is thinking. But are there other playlists like this? I am not looking for blitz games, but games of at least 10-minutes per side.
I am aware there are many video commentaries on grandmaster games, but I am looking specifically for games that are being commented on real-time by one of the players himself/herself.

I am sure this answer only scratches the surface of what you are asking for but here are some video narrations by the player for games of 10 minutes or longer.
Rapid Games:

Rapid Games by GM Hikaru Nakamura

The Sensei SpeedRun by GM Daniel Naroditsky

Beginner to Master Speedrun by GM Daniel Naroditsky

Master Class Speedrun by GM Daniel Naroditsky

Slowbrah by GM Aman Hambleton

Relaxing Rapid by GM Eric Hansen

Standard Chess (15-minute games) by IM John Bartholomew

How to Win at Chess by IM Levy Rozman (aka GothamChess)

Beginner to Master Speedrun by IM Eric Rosen

Rapid Chess with IM Eric Rosen by IM Eric Rosen

Chess Training Games by Stjepan Tomic (aka HangingPawns,  ≈ 1970 FIDE)



I second these videos. They are awesome. I would only add agadmator (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCL5YbN5WLFD8dLIegT5QAbA). He goes over GM games, and not in much detail as the above videos, but explains the fight in a very clear, succinct way.

@rougon I'm a fan but the OP asked for games where the player comments on video live during the player's own games, so Agadmator's recaps of GM games doesn't meet the criteria (though I also find them valuable)

Personally, I have found Levy Rozman's more comedic material surprisingly helpful as well (mostly because it is much, much better at keeping my attention than more serious content, and he does throw in some useful principles with the jokes).

YouTube search: Eric Rosen Chess.
The guy's really good and some of his longer games he takes the time to do this, and some of the times he doesn't. I've seen what this guy can do and how fast he can think. I've managed to learn a few things from him, despite his games being so far above my skill level.

Perhaps a bit dated - but also consider https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCP6ry1xoWJL5aiO8LxVabuw or similar

This show is great - with such greats as Gligorić and (very young) Short. Production technique used to get analysis boards was also very interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Master_Game#History_and_technique
